# How to search unique dynamic data in a sheet and then copy relevent row in diffrent sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am getting data from internet (Data>From Web) In sheet1. Then I disperse that data in to three sheets based on three unique text. Like a,b and c. Rows are copied to sheet a,b and c sheets depending on text (a,b,c) they have.
All the rows have one unique text (like url) by which they can be searched. I have added static data corresponding to the row.

The problem is when ever internet data is changed (row addition/substitution or randomized).
My static data loses its connection with the original row for which it was written. I want to search the data based on one unique key and put it to its original place where it used to be with static data.